# Mod dialog in review doesn't show up properly (and a bonus feature request)

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design, review

Let's start with the feature request.

[image: mod link on review answers]

[image: mod link on review questions]

When reviewing answers we have two mod links, when reviewing questions we only have the one. Having the mod link under the post feels a bit more natural, as that's where it normally is. Extremely insignificant feature request, I know, but coupled with the bug it's a bit more serious. Let's see what happens when you click the sidebar mod link:

[image: mod link bug]

Well, that's not right ;)

Lastly, when doing anything from the mod menu (the one that works), you're redirected to the post's page instead of the post's review page. Not sure if this is a bug or a feature request, but it would be nice if we were redirected back where we came from, to continue reviewing. And it would be *extra* nice if mod actions counted as review actions, mods love [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges) too!

Comment: +several million for the suggestion that mod actions count as review actions. We see most of the low quality stuff that way.

Comment: Would this feature request get more traction on MSO? I could see other sites benefit from this.

Comment: @jmort253 My main concern is fixing the bug, which is Programmers specific.

Comment: @jmort253 Why MSO? Should we be posting Meta questions that might apply everywhere there instead of Meta Programmers?

Comment: Hi @RocMartí, in general, if you know a bug exists on many sites, MSO would be the most appropriate place to report the bug. MSO is the "network meta" for all SE sites. However, it isn't wrong to post here either, as the mods can move or escalate bugs that need to be made visible to the developers.

Comment: @RocMartí If your Meta question is Programmers specific, you should ask it here (it would be closed as off topic on MSO). If not, then both Programmers Meta and MSO are valid choices (just don't post the same question in both).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Programmers CSS was just updated, so this bug is fixed now.

Regarding the bonus feature request: We're aware that the mod-menu-from-review flow is sub-optimal, and it's on our TODO. We just haven't prioritized it to the top yet, since it affects a small minority of users (albeit important ones).