# Bottom bar floating in middle of the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

The bottom bar (that black almost a straight line thing) is floating in the middle of the page on reviews.

This may be a regression of:

- [Footer line floats up too high in the main review page](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/footer-line-floats-up-too-high-in-the-main-review-page)
- [Line in UI goes under review tasks](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/line-in-ui-goes-under-review-tasks)
- [Image covers the review page](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5231/image-covers-the-review-page)

Safari (7.0.3 (9537.75.14)):
[image: Safari]

Chrome (34.0.1847.137):
[image: Chrome]

Firefox (28.0 <sup><sub>Yeah, I don't use it that much, though I just updated to 29.0.1 and its still there</sub></sup>):
[image: Firefox]

Note: the bottom bar *is* at the correct spot when doing close vote reviews on Meta.P.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy. Keep an eye out for revision 2014.6.24.1677.

The gist of the problem here was that the sidebar on Prog.SE is styled differently from other sites, so it requires [a bit more love to get the mod dialog to show up](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/mod-dialog-in-review-doesnt-show-up-properly-and-a-bonus-feature-request) when a moderator brings it up in /review. (Fun fact: there's a "mod" link beside the "link" link if you have a diamond.)

The original fix set us up for the issue reported here, and it should be fixed for good now. (I know, I know. Famous last words. :))

P.S. As a bonus, the mod dialog will also show up correctly on Prog.SE meta where it was until now still trying to fit into the sidebar.

Comment: Emmet mentioned a similar 'programmers is special"' in [this old answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5235/40980): "Programmers (along with Cooking and Ask Ubuntu) tends to require more one-off, site-specific CSS fixes than other sites."

Comment: Indeed. #thanksprogse